# Is the translation of this hadith undermining the true meaning?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, arabic, arabic-translation

The hadith in question is:

> مَنْ ضَارَّ أَضَرَّ اللَّهُ بِهِ وَمَنْ شَاقَّ شَاقَّ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ

Which translates to:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If anyone harms (others), Allah will harm him, and if anyone shows hostility to others, Allah will show hostility to him.

I'm not fluent in arabic, but I can't help but feel this translation is wrong. If it merely meant, "Allah would harm him" wouldn't the arabic say **"ضَارَّهُ اَللَّهُ"** instead of **"أَضَرَّ اللَّهُ بِهِ"** which implies Allah will harm him directly with the very same harm he inflicted on others because of the word **"بِهِ"**?
There is actually a similar [hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/2118150) that uses this alternative; which is why I ask this question.

A similar thing could be said about it being **"شَاقَّ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ"** with the usage of **"عَلَيْهِ"**.
The alternate hadith I linked actually implies this in the translation.

Now, I feel like I could be terribly wrong, but I'd appreciate any corrections and if anybody could help me gather a better understanding of this hadith.

Comment: This is not an Arabic translation site.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Then why do the tags exist..

Comment: For questions regarding the content of a translation from perspective of Islam.